# Unable to connect to AWS EC2 Instance - Connection Refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am new to AWS. I created a new AWS account and created an AWS Linux ESC2 instance and connected through SSH connection. I could run and install new libraries in python 3.7 as well. But then I tried to transfer a file to the instance using scp and since then I am not able to connect to the EC2 instance. This is the error I get:

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 2.8.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/../.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/../.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to ec2-{}.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
ssh: connect to host ec2-{}.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

When I try to ping the server using this:

```
curl -XGET '{Public IPv4 address}:22'
```

I get the same error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to {Public IPv4 address} port 22: Connection refused
```

I have already tried rebooting and restarting the instance and also I have already put my IP address in the inbound rules so that it is allowed but still I am not able to connect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are instance security groups?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I have just added an inbound rule? launch-wizard-1 is the name.

Comment: The `Connection refused` message says that network connectivity is fine (so the Security Group is okay), but the instance is rejecting your connection. Are you providing a keypair when connecting? What is the debug output if you use `ssh -vvv` when connecting?

Comment: Yes I provided the key. And the output that I have copied is from ssh -vvv command.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons -

- The host reached the instance but there was no service listening on the SSH port.
- A firewall blocked and was set to reject the package instead of dropping it.

Possible resolutions -

- Verify there isn't a firewall blocking the connection.
- Verify the SSH service is running on the instance.
- Verify the security group and network ACLs allow incoming traffic on TCP port 22.
- Verify the SSH TCP port 22 is in the listening state.

For more details how to solve this problem, please take a look at this [aws page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-resolve-ssh-connection-errors/).

Comment: I did try all these suggestions but nothing was working so I ended up termination the instance and made a new one. Till now i am not facing any issues even though I am doing nothing new.

Comment: Kind of bug seems to be, but to be kept in mind that this may happen